# Estimate Area Under Graph

Tags: calculus, area

Estimate the area under the graph of f(x) = 6/x from x = 1 to x = 7 using 6 approximating rectangles and right endpoints.

I keep getting 1 for delta x because (B-A)/N, and then I get values 1,3,6,10,15,21. Then I plug each of those into f(x), add them all together, but I'm not getting the correct answer. Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Delta x=1$ is correct.  Then you need to multiply by $f(x)$ at some point in the interval to get the area of the rectangle.  The third rectangle ranges from $x=3$ to $x=4$, so $f(x)$ ranges from $6/3=2$ to $6/4=1.5$.  Certainly it should not be $6$.

Comment: It must be the x values I'm getting wrong. I get the x values and plug each into f(x), then add them all together.

Comment: The $x$ values are just $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$, where the rectangles range from one to the one above.  Maybe you can explain where $21$ came from?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Shelby: You are, indeed, getting the $x$-values wrong. Note that it says "using...right endpoints." What they mean by that is that for the function value $f(x)$ on the interval $\bigl[A+k\Delta x,A+(k+1)\Delta x\bigr],$ you should "plug in" $x=A+(k+1)\Delta x.$ For example, on the interval $[5,6],$ you should plug in $6.$

Comment: Is 6 correct for the area of the first rectangle?

Comment: Yes if you use $f(x)$ values from the left side of the rectangle.  I missed the "right endpoints", so you should use $2$ for the $x$ value of the first rectangle-it ranges from $1$ to $2$.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot!